# CSV generator does not support Object values for properties (through reference chain)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a complex POJO generated from JSON.  Here is the Root which has several nested classes. The annotations are from Jackson annotations.

```
package edu.dlsu.esb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "data", "meta" })
public class Root {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private Meta meta;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("data", data).append("meta", meta)
                .append("additionalProperties", additionalProperties).toString();
    }

}
```

Which has nested POJOs like this.  Each with their own id and some are repeated. And this one has several other nessted classes like CreatedBy and UpdatedBy each with their own id.

```
package edu.dlsu.esb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "created_by_id", "updated_by_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "data", "collection_id",
        "created_by", "updated_by" })
public class Datum {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("created_by_id")
    private Integer createdById;
    @JsonProperty("updated_by_id")
    private Integer updatedById;
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data data;
    @JsonProperty("collection_id")
    private Integer collectionId;
    @JsonProperty("created_by")
    private CreatedBy createdBy;
    @JsonProperty("updated_by")
    private UpdatedBy updatedBy;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_by_id")
    public Integer getCreatedById() {
        return createdById;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_by_id")
    public void setCreatedById(Integer createdById) {
        this.createdById = createdById;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_by_id")
    public Integer getUpdatedById() {
        return updatedById;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_by_id")
    public void setUpdatedById(Integer updatedById) {
        this.updatedById = updatedById;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("collection_id")
    public Integer getCollectionId() {
        return collectionId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("collection_id")
    public void setCollectionId(Integer collectionId) {
        this.collectionId = collectionId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_by")
    public CreatedBy getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_by")
    public void setCreatedBy(CreatedBy createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_by")
    public UpdatedBy getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_by")
    public void setUpdatedBy(UpdatedBy updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("id", id).append("createdById", createdById)
                .append("updatedById", updatedById).append("createdAt", createdAt).append("updatedAt", updatedAt)
                .append("data", data).append("collectionId", collectionId).append("createdBy", createdBy)
                .append("updatedBy", updatedBy).append("additionalProperties", additionalProperties).toString();
    }

}
```

Here is the method I am using to generate csv from the Root pojo. That was populated from the JSON successfully.

```
public static final synchronized <T> String serialize(final T object, final Boolean withHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("serialize:" + object.toString());
        
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
        csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES);
        csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA);
        csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.INSERT_NULLS_FOR_MISSING_COLUMNS);
        csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        csvMapper.disable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);
            
        //csvMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN,true);
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(object.getClass());

        if (withHeaders) {
            csvSchema = csvSchema.withHeader();
        } else {
            csvSchema = csvSchema.withoutHeader();
        }

        return csvMapper.writer(csvSchema).writeValueAsString(object);
    }
```

Running this throws the following exception at that last line writer.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: CSV generator does not support Object values for properties (through reference chain: edu.dlsu.esb.Root["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->edu.dlsu.esb.Datum["data"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator._reportMappingError(CsvGenerator.java:925)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator.writeStartObject(CsvGenerator.java:535)
```

The pom.xml dependency with the jackson.version - 2.8.11

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`@JsonUnwraped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) to split the value into individual objects.

If you have multiple properties of the same type also utilize `prefix` attribute to prefix the property name when it splits.

Answer (score 2):

The [Limitations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/tree/2.8#limitations) section of the [Jackson CSV Dataformat](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/tree/2.8#overview) documentation for version 2.8 says:

> Due to tabular nature of `CSV` format, **deeply nested** data structures are **not** well **supported**.

You need to flatten the data yourself.

*NOTE:* The module is **deprecated** in 2.9, and has become part of [Jackson Text Dataformats](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text#overview) module.

Comment: Yes flattening is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the below java class, eventually, I removed "Agent Object" as below, then it works

```
package com.code.periodicreport.documents;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Data
@Document(indexName = "transactions-2021.07.19")
public class TransactionDocument {

    @Id
    @Field(value = "_id", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String id;

    @Field(value = "_index", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String index;

    @Field(value = "_type", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String type;

    @Field(value = "_score", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String score;

    @Field(value = "index_day", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String indexDay;

    @Field(value = "resourcePath", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String resourcePath;

    @Field(value = "merchantId", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String merchantId;

//    @Field(value = "agent", type = FieldType.Object)
//    private Agent agent;

    @Field(value = "partnerName", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String partnerName;

    @Field(value = "timestamp", type = FieldType.Date)
    private String timestamp;

    @Field(value = "app_id", type = FieldType.Integer)
    private int appId;
}
```